# How do you execute commands over ssh on cloudbuild?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am looking for ways to execute commands on to a remote server using ssh, when I am on cloudbuild.

Below is my current cloudbuild.yaml

```html
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - kms
  - decrypt
  - --ciphertext-file=build.pem.encrypted
  - --plaintext-file=build.pem
  - --location=asia-southeast1
  - --keyring=keyring
  - --key=build-key
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['chmod', '400', './build.pem']
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', './deploy.bash']
```

And my deploy.bash looks like this

```html
#! /bin/bash
apt update
apt install -y openssh-client

mkdir ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts

ssh-keyscan -H somedomain.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts


ssh -i build.pem -T -v somedomain.com 'bash -s deploy1.bash'
```

And my deploy1.bash looks like

```html
#! /bin/bash

echo "Hello World!"
echo "It works"
```

I have been trying out different ways to make it work. But could not.
If anybody could recommend how to make it work, I am very appreciated.

Currently I am it stuck at this step -

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve my issue.

The issue was actually from, sshguard, it's actually blocking the ssh session.